# Como compartilhar uma foto android

Tags: android

Tenho este *drawable*:

```
String nome_foto = itens.get(pos).nome_foto;
        int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(nome_foto, "drawable", getPackageName());
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable(drawableId);
```

tenho este drawable com a foto, como posso usá-la no compartilhar do *Android*.

Pensei em algo assim:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Aki precisa de um uri );
        sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.compartilhar)));
```

Porém precisa de um `uri` que não sei como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o share Action Provider, basicamente é um mecanismos de compartilhamento ajuda a você compartilhar conteúdo. Para maiores informações [documentação do Android](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html) que ele ira de ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode compartilhar uma foto desde que haja um caminho para ela. E a `URI` identifica este caminho, quando atribuído um valor em `string`.

> Busca a imagem no seu dispositivo através do caminho dado na URI]:

```
Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("file:///data/data/MINHA_PASTA_ANDROID/minhaimage.png");
imgview.setImageUri(imgUri);
```

### Agora você tem uma URI chamada: `imgUri`

```
...

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imgUri );

...
```

> No entanto, as vezes você pode querer pegar da pasta **drawable**:

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) + '/' +
                getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) + '/' +
                getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) );

//Testando
imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

Answer (score -3):

Tente desta forma:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/image_name");
```